# MIPS Runtime Error with "Cannot write directly to text segment"?

Tags: assembly, runtime-error, mips

I was trying to store something into a memory address and came across this error.

This is a sample of what I'm doing:

sll $11, $10, 2     #register $10 for this loop contain 1

mflo $9             # answer from previous calculations
                    # which is placed right above the sll instruction part

sw $9, 0($11)       # store answer in memory address ERROR occured

I tried to solve it by storing in a different register, make sure the memory address I'm going to use is empty, etc. but nothing seem to work... if you guys had encountered this problem, is there something you did to fix it?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: You show an insufficient amount of code. Please show the *complete* minimal example - a single assembly file that produces the executable that shows the problem. What OS is this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is really simple: *$11* does not point to writable memory. The value of *$11* is 4 (`1<<2`). You don't show enough code, but I presume that you initialize *$11* to point to a writable area, and then you overwrite it with the `SLL` instruction. Perhaps you meant something like this:

```
; Here $11 must contain an address of a writable memory area

SLL $12, $10, 2    ; $12 = $10[offset] * 4
ADD $12, $11, $12  ; $12 = $11[base] + offset*4
SW  $9, 0($12)     ; store $9 at at base+offset*4
```

Comment: But when I do "sw $9, 0($11)" doesn't that mean store whatever is in register 9 into mem[register 11 + 0]? thus this equal to mem[4] which should point to a memory address. Also what do you mean by $11 point to a writable area? I had the same exact code before this loop part, and it didn't give me any error

Comment: @Thankyouforyourhelp How do you know that the address `4` is writable? What OS does this code run on? Where did you get that address from? You can't just pick a number and say "hey, I'll write something there". The runtime error means that the address `4` is in the read-only text segment in your process.

Comment: @Thankyouforyourhelp By "pointing to a writable area" I mean that the register contains an address of an area of memory that you "own" and can write to. In your assembly code, you must define a data block within the data segment, assign it a label, and then set $11 to the value (address) of that label.

Comment: is there a way to change address 4 so that I can write to it? or have to skip it

Comment: @Thankyouforyourhelp Most likely there's some code or other data that doesn't belong to you at that address. If you modified the memory page's descriptor to make it writable, you'd make your program crash anyway. You need to understand how to define an area of writable data in your assembly code - this is environment- and assembler-specific. What assembler do you use, what version, what is the OS of the target?

Comment: I am using MARS and I just noticed something. If I stick to my code for right now, if the amount of integers inputted is small (let's say 100), then my code can store all those values in each memory address. But if I want it to store 4000 integers, then it will give me this error. I defined as :  .data 0x0   and .text 0x3000

Comment: Is there a way to store more numbers (like 4000 integers)? or there is no way to do that

Comment: @Thankyouforyourhelp Post the entire code. I can't keep pulling things out of you. To let us help you, you  absolutely, positively must post a self-contained, **minimal**, compileable example that demonstrates the problem. See http://www.sscce.org for details.